# ItemsControl view doesn't updated when an item in ObservableCollection is updated

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

**Introduction** :

Hi, I meet a weird problem here. My `ItemsControl` doesn't update the view if I am updating the model (e.g. changing the value of `IsSelected`).

One of `IsSelected` purpose however, is, if the value is `true`, then the Background of the `MusicalNotationBox` (UserControl) is changed to blue, and if it's `false` then it's changed back to transparent.

> A lot of person asked : *Why not using trigger such as* `Focus` *for* `IsSelected`*?* **Because** it's not just
>   for "visual" purposes. I have a Command which to change certain
>   `Property` (for example Note's Octave) of each `MusicalNotation`
>   object in VM's `MusicalNotations`, which `IsSelected==true` (support
>   multiselection), so I think I need `IsSelected` in the model. **But this is not the problem here, so please no answer solely on this matter.**

**The problem is :**

1. The model property is changed successfully (checked and verified), but it seems that **the view isn't**.
2. If I use the **singular form** of the UserControl, for e.g. `<c:MusicalNotationBox DataContext={Binding}/>` (ofc along with it's friends a.k.a correct properties in the VM), it **synced perfectly**. So, I'm not quite sure where the problem lies with the OC.
3. UPDATE : If I, for example create a MouseBinding that each time I click, then a new `MusicalNotation` added to the list, then, **the view is also updated.**

> I have read several topic (google and here) on "Observable Collection
>   doesn't update the ItemsControl`, but still found no satisfying answer.

**Here's my code (code may trimmed (...) for clarity sake) :**

**MODEL**

```
public class MusicalNotation : ... INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ...
    private bool _isSelected;
    ...
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected"); }
    }
    ...
    public MusicalNotation()
    {
        ...
        IsSelected = false;
    }
    ...
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
public class MainWindowModelView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<MusicalNotation> _musicalNotations;
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<MusicalNotation> MusicalNotations
    {
        get { return _musicalNotations; }
        set { _musicalNotations = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MusicalNotations"); }
    }

    public MainWindowModelView()
    {
        ...
        MusicalNotations = new ObservableCollection<MusicalNotation>();

        //Direct initialization for testing purpose
        MusicalNotations.Add(MusicalNotation.GetEmptyNote(new TimeSignature(4, 4)));
        MusicalNotations.Add(MusicalNotation.GetEmptyNote(new TimeSignature(4, 4)));

        foreach (MusicalNotation item in MusicalNotations)
        {
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<Window ...>
<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>
<Window.InputBindings>
    ...
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    ...        
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MusicalNotations, Mode=OneWay}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <c:MusicalNotationBox/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE, My MusicalNotationBox XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NumberedMusicScoresUserControl.MusicalNotationBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NumberedMusicScoresUserControl.MusicalNotationBoxProperties"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:DotConverter x:Key="DotConverter"/>
    <local:NoteConverter x:Key="NoteConverter"/>
    <local:AccidentalConverter x:Key="AccidentalConverter"/>
    <local:IsSelectedConverter x:Key="IsSelectedConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="10,5,10,5"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Background="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource IsSelectedConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
               Text="b"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource AccidentalConverter}, ConverterParameter=FL, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Path Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Accidental, Converter={StaticResource AccidentalConverter}, ConverterParameter=SP, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <Path.Data>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <LineGeometry.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" Angle="30"/>
                </LineGeometry.Transform>
            </LineGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Note, Converter={StaticResource NoteConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
               FontSize="15" FontFamily="CourierNew" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Margin="2.5,0,2.5,0"/>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=TOP, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Octave, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=BOT, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.Dot, Converter={StaticResource DotConverter}, ConverterParameter=RIGHT, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin}" Fill="{Binding Fill}" 
                         Width="{Binding Diameter}" Height="{Binding Diameter}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

(I didn't include it since, I think, if the "singular" one is correct, then my UserControl is correct as well. Might be wrong though.)

Comment: There's nothing binding to `IsSelected`. What's the code for the datatemplate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` for your user control is the `MusicalNotation` object, so while binding instead of using

```
Background="{Binding Path=MusicalNotation.IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource ....
```

just use

```
Background="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the MusicalNotation prefix from the bindings.

```
{Binding Path=IsSelected, ...
```

Comment: `IsSelected` is in `MusicalNotation` class. Anyway, I've tried it and no changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified any binding for the selected item or for the IsSelected in your xaml, that's why view is not being updated when the property is changed in the VM. For updating the view you will have to provide a binding for SelectedItem property of ItemsControl.

Comment: it's a user control, so such binding done in the user control code. But now I've included my usercontrol xaml as well. Please check it out.